# granular control of google maps zoom

Tags: google-maps-api-3

On google maps iOS app, when you pinch to zoom, you keep the zoom level you zoomed to.  In the js api v3, when you pinch to zoom, it snaps you the nearest zoom level.  Is there a way to maintain granular control of the zoom in the js api v3?

Comment: It looks like that is not a feature in API...

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible.

If you load [google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@37.4214055,-122.0816704,14z), you can see the zoom level in the URL. In this case it's 14z. If you use the slider controls, it changes the zoom level by 1. But if you use a mousewheel, it changes the zoom level more incrementally, from 14z to 14.38z, 14.65z, 14.93z. However if you try to load the URL with a partial zoom it will truncate down to 14z, unless it's 14.95z which rounds up to 15z.

However, if you load the same URL from a mobile browser it lacks this behavior. Instead it snaps to zoom levels like the javascript API map v3 map does. Therefore I believe this is not possible (yet?).